# Use Blazor as a Component

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Is it possible to use Blazor to create a webassembly component that can then be hosted inside a "traditional" HTML / JS application?

In my case I want to host it inside React, but that shouldn't matter.

---

I did take a look at Blazor, but from what I found so far it seems to be only possible to create Blazor **applications**, where the blazor framework will take care of initializing everything.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68889811/1768303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put this as a comment but I don't have the rep. I have been wondering the same and can only seem to find examples of rendering js/react components from inside a blazor app, not the other way around. A related issue has been raised on GitHub at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13766